# trouble getting bluetooth to work

Tags: bluetooth, proprietary-drivers

I'm having trouble getting my bluetooth hardware to work.  I have an ASUS PCE AX3000 wifi card and the wifi works ok (maybe some problems with it glitching out occasionally, I think it's a power management issue, but I can live with it).  I am using Linux Mint 20.1 Kernel 5.4.0-70-generic. The main problem is the bluetooth doesn't seem to work at all.

`service bluetooth status` returns

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-05-19 07:51:37 EDT; 11h ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 53546 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38332)
     Memory: 1.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─53546 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 19 07:51:37 desktop-home systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
May 19 07:51:37 desktop-home bluetoothd[53546]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
May 19 07:51:37 desktop-home systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
May 19 07:51:37 desktop-home bluetoothd[53546]: Starting SDP server
May 19 07:51:37 desktop-home bluetoothd[53546]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

The relevant part of `lspci -v` seems to be:

```
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35
    Memory at f6400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

When I look at `bluetoothctl` `show` I get `No default controller available`.

and

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
bluetoothctl: 5.53
```

I would appreciate guidance on next steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware was not installed correctly.  I reinstalled the card, and it now seems to work.  Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: false alarm? delete it then

Comment: I'm not totally sure on this... afterall, someone might have similar error codes in the future, and solve the problem by re-installing the hardware?